# Law of iterated logarithm for Brownian motion and simple random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The [law of iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) states that for a random walk $$S_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... X_n$$ with $X_i$ independent random variables such that $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$, we have

$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n / \sqrt{2 n \log \log n} = 1, \qquad \rm{a.s.}.$$
Similarly for Brownian motion $B(t)$ the law of iterated logarithm says
$$\limsup_{t \rightarrow \infty} B(t)/ \sqrt{2 t \log \log t} = 1, \qquad \rm{a.s.}.$$
However the central limit theorem for brownian motion says
$$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to B(t).$$
So how can we have the same scalling in the law of iterated logarithm?

Comment: $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges (in distribution) to $B(1)$, not $B(t)$, which is consistent with those two LILs. If by "central limit theorem for brownian motion" you meant Donsker Theorem, then it isn't about sequence $(S_n)_n$ but different sequence of processes $t \mapsto S_{[nt]}$, which again is consistent.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean $limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{B(1)}{\sqrt{2log log n}}=1$?

Comment: That is a bit meaningless, because $B(1)$ does not depend on $n$, hence this limsup is "obviously" zero almost surely.  The problem is that you neither cannot interchange limits as you like (the order of limits is important) nor you have almost sure convergence of $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ to $B(1)$ (only in distribution), so as you see, it is more delicate.

Comment: I see. I was just wondering what you meant by " consistent with those two LILs"?

Comment: Nothing precise at all, just that the variance of $S_n$ is $n$ and the mean is $0$. Similarly with the variance of $B(t)$ is $t$ and the mean is $0$, so in both cases you have suitably centered and normalised quanity (either $S_n$ or $B(t)$) divided by the same function, i.e. $f(x) = \sqrt{x\ln \ln x}$ (evaluated at $n$ and $t$ respectivelly).